# Auto image resize for iPhone/iPad gallery in portrait & landscape mode

Tags: jquery, iphone, gallery, autoresize, nivo-slider

I have to optimize a small website for iPhone and iPad. Thanks to media queries, I'm using two css files, one for iPhone portrait & landscape mode, and a second for iPad portrait & landscape + all others. There is a picture gallery on the website and I wanted the images to use the maximum available area depending on which device they are beeing displayed on, plus the orientation mode.

I ended up using 4 nivo sliders on the same page, where I hide 3 of 4 using css (display:none). The images are resized by TimThumb. This is definitely a bad solution (e.g. all 4 nivo sliders are beeing loaded and run on the iPhone even only one is displayed) and I was wondering if there is any other solution to this problem?

Comment: FYI: It's not possible to tell that you're asking about web development from reading the title or looking at the tags. I would say it's likely that this question doesn't attract the attention of the right people.

Comment: Any idea for better tags/title? Unfortunately I couldnt think of any better. :/ (I think you're right though.) - I changed it now but no idea if its any better than before.

Comment: you still don't use any words or tags that I associate with web development. All words and tags are perfectly valid for a question about app development in objective-c.

Comment: @Erik B - That was my problem while searching for a solution because most of the answers are app development related whereas I'm looking for a website gallery. Thanks anyway for trying to point me in the right direction.

Comment: I just read your question and I understand you're using nivo, which is a jQuery library, right? Try tagging your question jQuery and nivo. jQuery is a popular tag with lots of followers. Nivo is a tag that's not used a lot, but I guess it helps specify what you're working on.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem for ipad app and i simply used this:

> img.homepg {     width:920px; } @media screen and (max-width:910px)  {
>
> ```
> img.homepg { 
>     width:670px;  } } img { 
> transition:all .2s linear; 
> -o-transition:all .2s linear; 
> -moz-transition:all .2s linear; 
> -webkit-transition:all .2s linear; }
> ```

with .homepg being the img class, 920 being the largest image width, 910 being the max screen width that triggers the image resize (aka when the orientation is changed), and 670 being the min img width!

Comment: That does not seem to solve the OP issue which is : how to avoid the waste of bandwidth of 4 concurrent images on the same page ?